# A Transport-level error has occured when sending the request to the Server

Tags: .net, sql

Do anyone have a REAL and CLEAR way to solve this problem and an explaination of why it happens? Because, every thread i've read on how to solve this issue where not "politicaly correct". I mean, i saw things like "Restart machine, etc" but I get this error on a hosted dedicated server and I can't restart it like that.

> A transport-level error has occurred
>   when sending the request to the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Thanks a lot and again, sorry for my english, i'm from Quebec.

Comment: I've get another error when trying to reproduce the bug : "The semaphore timeout period has expired" ...

Comment: I've voting to close and migrate to serverfault.com - this appears to be a networking issue between your web server and your database server and possibly even an OS or hardware issue.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks you anyway. You help me to try things anyway! I will try serverfault.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the problem at the wrong end of the wire.  Pay a visit to the dba, bring gifts, work out a way to get notified about server reboots.

Comment: You mean what? It could be because the server had reboot? There's currently missing a lot of people everywhere because of vacation...

Comment: Server error. Not our problem. They finaly solve it. They needed a level 3 to solve it...

Comment: I'm 17034 at this site.  They count down though.

Comment: No, I mean a level 3 technician where the DB is :OP.

Comment: Lol, even the tech tought it was solve but the problem comes back. I'll post here the solution once we know it.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen for a number of reasons, but like the error message says, this is at the transport level of the connection to the SQL Server.

Is your client/web server and SQL Server running on the same machine?  This will be very rare in that case, since the network between them is static.

Is your connection to the server stable?  Are you connecting over a WAN?  Is the server subject to maintenance windows?  Are there any firewall issues?

Comment: Wow loll. My head programmer is in Vacation now and thats why I'm in charge of that problem. But I don't know much about everyting you ask me to. All I can tell you is that I know that both have seperated server. But, can you tell me things I could try instead of thing i should know? Thanks !!!

Comment: It is really difficult to give you answer better than this. We only know that you get connection error. @Cade Roux is absolutely right that there are more than one reasons of this.

Comment: @Simon we need to know a lot more.  Are you saying all operation besides SELECT are failing?  How are you connecting to the server?  When you see this error, are you seeing it in a web page, in a client application or in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: SELECT works fine. INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE fails on a .NET application coded. We've getting a yellow page error raised by our web application. 

But sorry @Cade Roux, I woudn't say that your answer were not good, absolutly not. I know it's good. But, I mean that i'm not good enough in SQL and I must try something to solve it. Thanks

Comment: @Simon I think it will just have to wait until someone gets back from vacation who knows how your application is architected.

Comment: So you are selcting from the same .net application? or are you selecting from the query window? Have you tried an insert from the query window and not the application? If that works then the problem may be in your .net connection.

Comment: Well, now we've notice that the error getting less often than yesterday but it now also fails on selects query. So, all query type now get randomly the error. We've getting the error only from our web application. I've tried querying with SQL Management Studio and it works fine (With the same User/password informations)